# Best way to express a union of all NumPy scalar types?

Tags: python, numpy, python-typing

I would like to declare type annotations for an argument that is forwarded to the `dtype` argument of a NumPy array constructor:

```
def f(n: int, dtype: <???>):
    return np.zeros(n, dtype=dtype)
```

What should `<???>` be in this declaration?

I'd prefer not to use `np.dtype` because that would force the caller to construct, e.g. `np.dtype(np.int32)` instead of passing the bare `np.int32`.

Comment: The `dtype` argument can also be a string, e.g. `dtype='>U3'`.

Comment: Never used type annotations before but `isinstance(np.dtype,type)` returns True so you might be able to use that.

Comment: If you only want scalar types, the numpy ones,  but not the pure Python ones, seem to all derive from `np.generic`, although its own docstring isn't 100% sure about this.

Comment: And compound dtypes work, e.g. 'i,f,U3', `[('x', int, (4))]`.

Comment: How are you using or testing these annotations?   As far as I know, `numpy` has not  been adapted to `typing` and `mypy`.  But if the annotations are just for documentation purposes, use what ever makes sense to you and your users.